# Unexpected outcome with merging react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Once finding the weather and having it displayed, clicking on Celsius is supposed to run a `unitHandler` that will then convert the value of the temperature, and then update the state. However, when updating `this.state.currentWeather.temp` (a property that already exists, so I thought it would do a 'shallow' merge, and just 'update' the state), it wipes out the rest of the currently existing state properties.

I'd like to know why it doesn't do a 'shallow' merge the way the React Docs show an example of [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), and instead wipes out the rest of my state? Is it because React sometimes batches multiple `setState()` calls for performance, as shown below from the docs?

> State Updates May Be Asynchronous React may batch multiple setState()
>   calls into a single update for performance.
>
> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you
>   should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

I think I'm just confused because right below that in the docs, it says it will leave the rest of the other state intact, when updating/merging:

> State Updates are Merged When you call setState(), React merges the
>   object you provide into the current state. The merging is shallow, so
>   this.setState({comments}) leaves this.state.posts intact, but
>   completely replaces this.state.comments.

Doing some research, I think a way I could prevent this is by passing in a `prevState` function into `this.setState`, however, I am failing to correctly write the function using the spread operator.

```js
const root = document.querySelector('.root');

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      unit: '',
      currentWeather: {
        main: '',
        desc: '',
        temp: '',
      }
    }
    
    this.getWeather = this.getWeather.bind(this);
    this.unitHandler = this.unitHandler.bind(this);
  }
  
  getWeather(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const country = e.target.elements.country.value;
    const appID = 'bf6cdb2b4f3c1293c29610bd1d54512b';
    
      const currentWeatherURL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&units=imperial&APPID=${appID}`;
    const forecastURL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city},${country}&units=imperial&APPID=${appID}`;
    
    //fetch CURRENT weather data ONLY
    fetch(currentWeatherURL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          unit: '°F',
          currentWeather: {
           main: data.weather[0].main,
           desc: data.weather[0].description,
           temp: data.main.temp,
          }
        });
    })
    .catch(() => {console.log('something went wrong, but we caught the error')});
  }
  
  unitHandler(e) {
    function convertToCelsius(fahrenheit) {
      return ((fahrenheit-32)*5/9)
    }
    
    function convertToFahrenheit(celsius) {
      return ((celsius*9/5) + 32)
    }
    
    //if fahrenheit is checked
    if(e.target.value === 'fahrenheit') {
      const fahrenheitTemp = convertToFahrenheit(this.state.currentWeather.temp);
      this.setState({unit: '°F',currentWeather: {temp: fahrenheitTemp}});
    } 
    //otherwise, celsius is checked
    else {
      const celsiusTemp = convertToCelsius(this.state.currentWeather.temp);
      this.setState({unit: '°C', currentWeather: {temp: celsiusTemp}});
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    console.log('handler state');
      console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className='weather-app'>
        <LocationInput getWeather={this.getWeather} unitHandler={this.unitHandler}/>
        <CurrentWeather weatherStats={this.state.currentWeather} unit={this.state.unit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// Component where you enter your City and State 
function LocationInput(props) {
  return (
    <div className='location-container'>
      <form className='location-form' onSubmit={props.getWeather}>
         <input type='text' name='city' placeholder='City'/>
         <input type='text' name='country' placeholder='Country'/>
        <button>Search</button>
        <UnitConverter unitHandler={props.unitHandler} />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

// Component to convert all units (fahrenheit <---> Celsius)
function UnitConverter(props) {
  return (
    <div className='unit-converter' onChange={props.unitHandler}>
      <label for='fahrenheit'>
        <input type='radio' name='unit' value='fahrenheit' defaultChecked/>
        Fahrenheit
      </label>
      <label for='celsius'>
        <input type='radio' name='unit' value='celsius'/>
        Celsius
      </label>
    </div>
  )
}

// Base weather component (intention of making specialized components for weekly forecast)
function Weather (props) {
  console.log('component state');
  console.log(props);
   const icons = {
        thunderstorm: <i class="fas fa-bolt"></i>,
        drizzle: <i class="fas fa-cloud-rain"></i>,
        rain: <i class="fas fa-cloud-showers-heavy"></i>,
        snow: <i class="far fa-snowflake"></i>,
        clear: <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>,
        atmosphere: 'No Icon Available',
        clouds: <i class="fas fa-cloud"></i>,
      };
  
  let currentIcon = icons[props.weatherStats.main.toLowerCase()];

  return (
    <div className={'weather-' + props.type}>
      <h1>{props.location}</h1>
      <h2>{props.day}</h2>
      <figure className='weather-icon'>
        <div className='weather-icon'> 
          {currentIcon}
        </div>
        <figcaption>
          <h3 className='weather-main'>{props.weatherStats.main}</h3>
          <div className='weather-desc'>{props.weatherStats.desc}</div>
          {props.weatherStats.temp && <div className='weather-temp'>{Math.round(props.weatherStats.temp)}{props.unit}</div>}
        </figcaption>
      </figure>      
    </div>
  ) 
}

// Using the specialization concept of React to create a more specific Weather component from base
function CurrentWeather(props) {
  const dateObj = new Date();
  const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'];
  const currentDay = days[dateObj.getDay()];
  
  return (
    <Weather 
      type={'current'} 
      weatherStats={props.weatherStats} 
      day={currentDay}
      unit={props.unit}
      />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

```css
.weather-app {
  text-align: center;
}

.weather-current {
  display: inline-block;
}

.wf-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div class="root"></div>
```

Comment: Please add all your relevant code here, there is no need to have to go to an external site to see your attempt

Comment: @Icepickle Sorry about that, updated.

Comment: React shallow merges state so that means it only looks at the top level properties of your state object but `temp` is nested into `currentWeather` which react will entirely replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you replace the current weather object entirely. You must keep the other current weather properties in order to make it work properly:

```
this.setState((state) => ({
    unit: '°C',
    currentWeather: {
        ...state.currentWeather,
        temp: celsiusTemp
    }
}));
```

Of course, you must do the same for the other conversion method.

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PxgRwM) is the working example.

Comment: Correct but it should be noted that you should use the callback version of `setState` when updating the state based on the current state or props as otherwise react may override previous changes when they are batched.

Comment: Well that depends on the logic of the script. If you update multiple properties in the  currentWeather object then of course you need to make sure all the changes are set in the state.

Comment: Maybe but it is a good practice to use the callback in my opinion. The docs say: "Pass an updater function instead of an object if you need to compute values based on the current state". Currently updates are only batched inside of event handlers but this is an implementation detail that you should not rely on and that can change in future versions of react. If you don't use a callback while updating from current state your code can break.

Comment: @trixn done.. you're right. I think this is a recommendation in the new version of react? I never heard about it before..

Comment: The recommendation has been there since I started using react which is about two years. But it is quite hidden and can be probably be overlooked quite easily. For reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value

Answer (score 3):

Your setState() should look like this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ 
  ...prevState, 
  currentWeather: { ...prevState.currentWeather, temp: celsiusTemp } 
}));
```